# UITableView as subview of UITextView not properly displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete `UITextView`. The auto-suggestion is working fine. But the `UITableView` is getting clipped off. Please look at the image below.
[image]

The `greybox` is the actual `UITableView`. This `UITableView` is defined in another `.xib` file and is being called from another `ViewController`.

```
autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 35) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.textViewCell addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
```

here `autocompleteTableView` is the `UITableView` and `textViewCell` is the `UITextView`. And this is getting called from another ViewController which makes the autocomplete box to constrict to `UITextView` size.

What i want to achieve is something like this : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem would appear to be because of the view you are adding the table view as a subview of. Even if the table view was visible it most likely wouldn't respond to touches because of the `frame` of the superview (taps outside the `frame` aren't handled).

You should consider doing something like adding a new view higher up the view hierarchy which replaces (overlays) the text field and adds the table view. This needs to be added high enough up the hierarchy that the host view is big enough to fully contain the new view (so, the view controllers view).

It should work if you handle the text field as you currently are but add just the table view at the top level of the view hierarchy.